# Testing phantomJS scripts

Tags: unit-testing, phantomjs

I have a phantomjs script that navigates to some pages and store some information about them in a file. Now I want to unit test this script. My problem is that usually the frameworks test my code on client side, so I can't use the PhantomJS API.

I tried to use jasmine-node (https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node). It works "server-side", but I can't use all the PhantomJS API because it obviously run my tests with nodejs instead of phantom. Is there a better option to test PhantomJS apps at server-side?

Answer (score 1):

I found two solutions. I think the most complete way to test phantomJS at "server side" is to use [CasperJS](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/tester.html).

Another solution I have found looking at the phantomjs source code. They use jasmine for testing and it's possible to apply the same idea to my own tests. The [run-tests.js](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/test/run-tests.js) is the starting point for this approach.